# How to ensure that clients are able to connect to a SSL connection with Strong Cipher

Tags: apache, encryption, ssl

I have a website and various clients(Web and Mobile) access it. I have used the following CipherSuite

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
```

But this CipherSuite accepts Low ciphers and SSLv2 which can lead to security issues. So i used the following CipherSuite

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
```

But now how can i ensure that my clients will be able to access the website. Is there some other way to maintain the security of the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using

```
    SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH
```

which is supposed to mitigate the [BEAST attack](http://blog.ivanristic.com/2011/10/mitigating-the-beast-attack-on-tls.html).

Comment: Thats Nice. What about the accessibility of clients and What about TLS/SSL Renegotiation? Also i am using Apache 2.2

Comment: I'm not aware of any clients that don't support these suites. This is a working configuration. You didn't mention renegotiation in your question, so I didn't address it in my answer. I am also using Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Take the guesswork out of the configuration by using a tool such as the **[Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/)** to check which configuration you should use.

[image]

(as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284345/139040))